# RxJava: How to postprocess subset of items, but return full list to caller

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, reactivex

I am writing a REST client that talks to a remote server and needs to do something similar to this:

- Retrieve list of items from remote server
- Compare received list with local data
- For any items that have been modified locally (possibly none), submit changes to server
- Finally, return the complete list of items to the caller

I am using RxJava (2) and I am struggling a bit with the implementation. I think it should be more or less like this (pseudo code):

```
public Single<List<Item>> synchronize()
{
    return server.fetchItems().flatMap(receivedItemList -> {
        List<Single<Item>> syncList = new List<>();
        for (Item item : receivedItemList) {
            if (item.needsSync()) {
                Single<Item> modifiedItem = server.updateItem(item);
                syncList.add(modifiedItem);
            }    
        }

        if (!syncList.empty()) {
            return Single.zip(syncList,
                              items -> {
                                  // Changes have been sync'ed,
                                  // return full list to caller
                                  return receivedItemList;
                              });
        } else {
            return Single.just(receivedItemList);
        }
    });
}
```

I am not sure whether this is the right approach: For example the zipper function is returning the full list if items to the caller -- I am using zip mostly to make sure that all updates are done before completing operation. Also the fact that I am calling Single.zip() in one case and Single.just() in the other feels a bit wrong.

Does this look correct? Is this the idiomatic way to do this with RxJava? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

you'r close to the Rx way of doing this, however some changes to the code may enhance it a little, so those some notes on your code, I'll follow this with my humble implementation.

- each time you think to use a for loop in Rx, try `fromIterable()` operator, this operator emit item by item so you could do your logic on it like filtering.
- there is a lot of filtering operators in Rx, so you don't have to write checks in the stream. the most popular one is `filter()` which take predicate as argument and rturn an Observable type.
- if you want to collect emissions in one list there is an operator called `toList()` to emit the whole list.

now to the implementation

```java
  public Observable<List<String>> fetchNetworkItems() {
    return Observable.just(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C")); //maybe retrofit
  }

  public Observable<List<String>> localItems() {
    return Observable.just(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C")); //maybe Room
  }

  public Completable updateRemoteItem(String localItem) {
    return Completable.create(emitter -> {
      //update logic if things are going well use emitter.onComplete();
      //catch any exception  or errors --> use emitter.onError() to throw it
    });
  }

  public Single<List<String>> updateRemoteItems() {
    return fetchNetworkItems().flatMap(Observable::fromIterable) //iterate over the remote items
        .flatMap(remoteItem -> localItems().flatMap(Observable::fromIterable) //iterate over the local items
            .filter(localItem -> !localItem.equals(remoteItem)) //decide which one need to update
            .flatMap(localItem -> updateRemoteItem(localItem).andThen(Observable.just(localItem))) //update then get the local item
            .defaultIfEmpty(remoteItem) //since no need to update it doesn't matter which item we return, we have access to the remote
        ).toList();
  }
```

with the help of `fromIterable()` and `flatMap()` and filtering operators you can achieve the nested loop logic in a functional way.

> **Edit**: the following implementation, if you want to update all items in
>   parallel, note that with `zip()` if one api call fail, that cause all
>   other calls to fail.

```java
  public Observable<List<String>> fetchNetworkItems() {
    return Observable.just(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C")) //maybe retrofit
        .subscribeOn(io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers.io());//do work in background

  }

  public Observable<List<String>> localItems() {
    return Observable.just(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C")) //maybe Room
        .subscribeOn(io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers.io());//do work in background
  }

  public Observable<String> updateRemoteItem(String localItem) { //may be retrofit
    return Observable.just(localItem)
        .subscribeOn(io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers.io());//do work in background
  }

  public List<Observable<String>> generateApisCall(List<String> remotesToBeUpdated) {
    return Observable.fromIterable(remotesToBeUpdated)
        .map(this::updateRemoteItem)
        .toList()
        .blockingGet();
  }

  public Single<List<String>> getItemsToUpdate() {
    return fetchNetworkItems()
        .doOnNext(strings -> {/*may be save the list to access later*/}) //side effects is not a good thing, but that's best what I thought for now.
        .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable) //iterate over the remote items
        .flatMap(remoteItem -> localItems().flatMap(
            Observable::fromIterable) //iterate over the local items
                .filter(localItem -> (localItem/*.id*/ == remoteItem/*.id*/) /* && remoteItem.old()*/)
            //decide which one need to update
        ).toList();
  }

  public void update() {
    getItemsToUpdate()
        .subscribeOn(io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe((strings, throwable) -> {
          Observable.zip(generateApisCall(strings), objects -> "success").subscripe(string -> {}, throwable -> {});
        });
  }
```

this is more like a pseudo code, so try to test it, and the type `Item` here is replaced by type `String`.

Comment: Uhm, interesting. But with this approach, the updateRemoteItem calls would not be done in parallel, right?

Comment: @Grodriguez yes, you're right, I'll update my answer,

Comment: @Grodriguez you can check the code now, hope this could help you.

Comment: But now, the synchronize() method is no longer returning the full list to the caller -- or am I missing something ?

Comment: You're right again, but that's the best what I can do for now. If I came up with better solution, I'll let you know